# Python and MySQL data printing

Tags: python, mysql

I want to print data from MySQL database. When I will start the program, data from 2021-02-17 12:26:03 to currently time will be printed, but the data sent now aren't print in the next steps.

```
import mysql.connector
from os import system, name
from time import sleep
import datetime
fetch_from = ""
fetch_to = ""

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root",
  database="python"
)
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
fetch_from = "2021-02-17 12:26:03"
while True:
  sleep(2)
  dt = datetime.datetime.now()
  fetch_to = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
  mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
  messages = mycursor.execute('select * from chat where created_at BETWEEN "%s" and "%s"' % (fetch_from, fetch_to))
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
  for x in myresult:
    print(x)
  fetch_from = fetch_to
  print("from", fetch_from, "to", fetch_to)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have commits between the select queries. Try adding: mydb.autocommit(True) after creating the connection or committing in your loop.

Comment: I think you need to have commits between the select queries.  Try adding:
mydb.autocommit(True) after creating the connection or committing in your loop.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I added it here:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root",
  database="python",
  autocommit=True
)
```